# Outer join operator error

Tags: sql, oracle

Earlier I was filtering my query only on one condition. ie **project_id** But now I added two more conditions for filtering. And they are

1. Date IN
2. Vehicle No.

I tried with the below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT sv.mkey, vehicle_no,
               TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
            || ' & '
            || time_in vehicleindate_time,
               TO_CHAR (date_out, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
            || ' & '
            || time_out vehicleoutdate_time,
            gate_no_in || ' & ' || gate_no_out ingate_outgateno,
            gd.good_type goods_type, net_weight netweight,
               TO_CHAR (challan_date, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
            || ' & '
            || challan_no challandate_no,
            remark_in remarkin, NULL receipt_no, date_in
       FROM xxcus.xxgid_supinv sv,
            xxcus.xx_supinv_goodtype gd,
            xxcus.xxacl_xxgid_user_mst ms
      WHERE gd.good_type_code(+) = sv.good_type AND sv.project_id = 1469
         OR TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd/MM/yyyy') = '09/01/2015'
         OR vehicle_no = '79'
   ORDER BY date_in DESC, vehicle_no
```

But got error as

> ORA-01719: outer join operator (+) not allowed in operand of OR or IN

I don't know what's going wrong here. kindly suggest

Comment: Use new syntax - LEFT/RIGHT/FULL OUTER JOIN instead of (+)

Comment: @Tatiana: but it is working perfectly if I use only one condition

Comment: how is ms table joined to rest of query?

Comment: @Matt: **ms table** ?? is there something wrong with the query ?

Comment: `xxcus.xxacl_xxgid_user_mst ms` isnt joined in any way

Comment: @Matt: oh year you are right.. may be I didn't saw it. how can I join these for more filterations

Comment: @coder I dont know what it _should_ join too? Its your data what do you want it to join on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101176/discussion-between-coder-and-matt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use explicit `JOIN`'s and also you need to define what joins `xxcus.xxacl_xxgid_user_mst ms` to the rest of your query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT sv.mkey, vehicle_no,
                TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd/MM/yyyy') || ' & ' || time_in vehicleindate_time,
                TO_CHAR (date_out, 'dd/MM/yyyy') || ' & ' || time_out vehicleoutdate_time,
                gate_no_in || ' & ' || gate_no_out ingate_outgateno,
                gd.good_type goods_type, net_weight netweight,
                TO_CHAR (challan_date, 'dd/MM/yyyy') || ' & ' || challan_no challandate_no,
                remark_in remarkin, NULL receipt_no, date_in
FROM xxcus.xxgid_supinv sv
RIGHT OUTER JOIN xxcus.xx_supinv_goodtype gd ON sv.good_type = gd.good_type_code
XXXX JOIN xxcus.xxacl_xxgid_user_mst ms ON XX.XXXXX ON ms.XXXXX
WHERE sv.project_id = 1469
OR TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd/MM/yyyy') = '09/01/2015'
OR vehicle_no = '79'
ORDER BY date_in DESC, vehicle_no
```

Comment: getting error as `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` at **xxcus.xxacl_xxgid_user_mst ms**

Comment: @coder Read what i written !!!!`you need to define what joins xxcus.xxacl_xxgid_user_mst ms to the rest of your query.`!!!!!

Comment: all columns belongs to `xxcus.xxgid_supinv` so which join shd I use

Answer (score 0):

You are using (+) syntax, which does not allow the use of OR conditions; you could re-write your query using explicit OUTER JOIN; for example:

```
SQL> create table table_id ( id number);

Table created.

SQL> create table table_desc ( id number, description varchar2(255));

Table created.

SQL> begin
  2  insert into table_id values (1);
  3  insert into table_id values (2);
  4  insert into table_id values (3);
  5  insert into table_desc values (1, 'ONE');
  6  insert into table_desc values (3, 'THREE');
  7  insert into table_desc values (3, 'Three');
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Wrong way:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from table_id id, table_desc des
  3  where id.id = des.id(+)
  4    and des.description = 'Three' OR des.description = 'THREE';
where id.id = des.id(+)
            *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-01719: outer join operator (+) not allowed in operand of OR or IN
```

Right way:

```
SQL> select id.id, des.description
  2  from table_id id
  3       LEFT OUTER JOIN table_desc des
  4        ON id.id = des.id
  5  where des.description = 'Three' OR des.description = 'THREE';

        ID DESCRIPTION
---------- -------------------
         3 Three
         3 THREE

SQL>
```